# How to pick hourly values from dataset?

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I need help with this issue:

I have a dataset of water level values distributed every 30 minutes, but I need only the hourly values. I tried with the `aggregate()` function but due to function `FUN` is one requisite it determines my analysis to be mean, or median and I don't want to use any stat function.

This one example of my data frame

```
06/16/2015 02:00:00 0.036068
06/16/2015 02:30:00 0.008916
06/16/2015 03:00:00 -0.008622
06/16/2015 03:30:00 -0.014057
06/16/2015 04:00:00 -0.011172
06/16/2015 04:30:00 0.002401
06/16/2015 05:00:00 0.029632
06/16/2015 05:30:00 0.061902002
06/16/2015 06:00:00 0.087366998
06/16/2015 06:30:00 0.105176002
06/16/2015 07:00:00 0.1153
06/16/2015 07:30:00 0.126197994
06/16/2015 08:00:00 0.144154996
```

Comment: This picks out every other row: `DF[c(TRUE, FALSE), ]` starting with first row.

Comment: Thanks, thats ok and helped me! but I have other dataset in which the time step is 1 minute. So in that case I would need other algorithm to select hourly values.

Comment: I tried to do it using this function:

Comment: Newforecasteddata <-aggregate(list(Newforecasteddata = Newforecasteddata$Values1),list(DateTime1 = 
                                                                                      cut(Newforecasteddata$DateTime1,"1 hour")),mean)
but I got undiserable mean values. Thanks!

Comment: Can you `dput()` your data.frame? It's unclear what classes your columns are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We convert the 'RefDateTimeRef' column to `POSIXct`, extract the 'minute', 'second' with `format` and compare it with `00:00` to return a logical vector which we use to subset the rows.

```
df1[format(as.POSIXct(df1[,1], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%M:%S")=="00:00",]
#     RefDateTimeRef  Data
#10 04/14/2016 09:00 0.153
#22 04/14/2016 08:00 0.148
```

---

Or with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
df1[ minute(mdy_hm(df1[,1]))==0,]
#     RefDateTimeRef  Data
#10 04/14/2016 09:00 0.153
#22 04/14/2016 08:00 0.148
```

---

Or with `sub` to remove the substring until the hour part and then use `==` to get the logical vector and subset the rows.

```
df1[ sub(".*\\s+\\S{2}:", "", df1[,1])=="00",]
```

NOTE: I would advice against using `sub` or `substr` as it can sometimes lead to incorrect answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
df <- read.table(text = '06/16/2015 02:00:00 0.036068
06/16/2015 02:30:00 0.008916
06/16/2015 03:00:00 -0.008622
06/16/2015 03:30:00 -0.014057
06/16/2015 04:00:00 -0.011172
06/16/2015 04:30:00 0.002401
06/16/2015 05:00:00 0.029632
06/16/2015 05:30:00 0.061902002
06/16/2015 06:00:00 0.087366998
06/16/2015 06:30:00 0.105176002
06/16/2015 07:00:00 0.1153
06/16/2015 07:30:00 0.126197994
06/16/2015 08:00:00 0.144154996')

colnames(df) <- c('Date','Time','Value')

index <- ifelse(substring(df$Time,4) == "00:00",T,F)

final_df <- df[index,]
```